# IBM Worklight - How to Launch android emulator?

Tags: android, ibm-mobilefirst

I have created an IBM worklight project and added the Android environment. When I right-click the Android folder and select Run As, I do not find "run in application".

Additionally, when I Run As Android Studio project, I get an error:

> Failed Running Android Studio: Specify location of Android Studio in
>   Window->Preferences->Worklight

Answer (score 1):

If you did not [install Android Studio,](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/studio.html) it will **obviously** not work for you.
Verify you have properly installed Android Studio.

Also make sure that you right-click on the **generated** Android project. There, you will find under the Run As entry, the "Android application" option.

Additionally make sure you have first created an AVD (Android Virtual Device == the emulator...). [Follow this guide](http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/index.html).

[image]